# Scrolling a table with multiple fixed table headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, html-table

Before I attempt to reinvent the wheel (via jQuery plugin or similar), I'm trying to see if there is an easier way to do this or an existing plugin that users may know of.  What I'm looking to do is scroll the body of a table that contains multiple table headers.  For example, imagine something of this structure:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Honestly, I haven't tried out the above syntax to even see if its valid.  The actual markup I have does not currently use thead/tbody and instead scrolls the whole parent div (seen below).

[image: example table with multiple headers]

What I want to achieve is scrolling of the whole table such that the header of the most relevant section is viewed on top.  Currently the header scrolls out of view is there are enough rows.

I know the various techniques used to scroll a table with one header, but what about multiple?  Are there any existing ways to achieve this?  I'm open to different ideas, but right now I'm thinking of simply displaying the most relevant table header for the content on top.

Comment: This is a pretty specialized case - It may have been done before, but I doubt you'll find an existing plugin.  Are you just looking for answers that point you to an existing plugin, or are you looking for help "inventing the wheel"?

Comment: here is jquery plugin for sticky header http://polarblau.github.com/stickySectionHeaders/ but it's for 'ul' list not table. This example might help you too http://jsfiddle.net/6qqPz/

Comment: @satrun77: Thanks, those actually look really interesting.  Might be onto something there.

Comment: @gilly3: I'm more than willing to invent the wheel if need be, but before I go on that endeavor, I wanted to see if it already has been done. If it has not, ideas for features/functionality are definitely welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A few months ago, I wrote some code that did exactly that where I wanted the headers to perform similar to section headers on iOS.
Utilising a Jquery, the solution I ended up with involved creating an onScroll (and onResize for window resizing) event listener that ran a check through all `$('table thead')` and checked their `$(this).position()` on the page.

The check was whether the `thead` had a position which was above the top of the current viewport.

Once I had found the most relevant header (the bottommost `thead` that was above the viewport), I created a new `table`, with `position: fixed` at (0, 0) and copied into it a new column for each column of the headers rows and manually set its `width` properties to match the original table.

[I have put together a Proof of Concept which shows how this all works](https://jsfiddle.net/21qch0v5/).

Here is some pseudo-code of how it works:

1. Check the table is visible
2. Get a list of all `thead` sections in the table
3. Reverse the list
4. Find the first `thead` in the array with a top position less than `scrollTop` of the `body` element
5. If we found one:

   1. Create deep copy of the thead
   2. Make a container table
   3. Copy attributes from the original table so the styles get copied
   4. Position the container at `[0, originalTable.left]`
   5. Set the width equal to the `outerWidth` of the original table
   6. Set the width of every `td` found to the width of the matching `td` from the original table
   7. Add it to the DOM
6. If none found, remove the existing container from the DOM if there was one

There are some other edge case details that made this even nicer too:

- Instead of (0, 0), the origin point for the fixed row was altered based upon whether the "real" header row for the `tbody` below the one with the fixed header should be pushing it away.
- Ensure that previous header rows are deleted before making a new one
- Don't recreate the header row if the header you'd be making is the same as what is already there

---

This approach worked a lot better others I tried such as trying to `position:absolute` an object due to the fact that Firefox and IE aren't incredibly fast at running the onScroll handler so you tend to see 'juddering'. I also tried mucking with the `position` attribute of the `thead`s, this just ended in the table column widths jumping about and not matching the data.

`thead` nodes aren't strictly required for this solution as you can use some other selector to determine which rows are headers etc.

---

**Update**: Added example code and pseudo-code
**Update**: Dropbox changed their system, replaced example with jsfiddle URL

Comment: +1 nice demo, is the text below just to show the lack of interference with other elements?

Comment: @Josh Yep, bingo. The text is simply to show that the header disappears when the table isn't visible

Comment: @AlexTaylor This is pretty sweet. Awesome example/job.

Comment: This looks really nice. I would be interested to know if you've made anything similar without tables. I'm looking for a scrolling div, where the persistent headers are `<h3>` rather than table headers.

Comment: @rybo111 see satrun77's comment on the question which points to a jQuery plugin http://polarblau.github.com/stickySectionHeaders/ with example: http://jsfiddle.net/6qqPz/